# Remove particular objects from an array based on objects from another array

Tags: iphone, ios, filter, nsarray

Setup: Have a `UITableView` which shows US golf courses with name, street, state etc.
`UITableView's` data source is a `NSMutableArray` of objects from my class `GolfCourse` called `allGolfCourses`.

Now I like to remove all west coast golf courses from `allGolfCourses` and create a new `array` called `eastCoastGolfCourses`. I have another `NSArray` with `string objects` of all west coast states (Abbreviations) called `westCoastStates` but having a hard time connecting these two.

How do I iterate through allGolfCourses and remove all objects which have a state Abbreviations found in  `westCoastStates` array?

**westCoastStates Array:**

```
self.westCoastStates = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                        @"CH",
                        @"OR",
                        @"WA",
                        nil];
```

**GolfCourse.h**

```
@interface GolfCourse : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *longitude;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *latitude;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *clubName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *state;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *courseInfo;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *street;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *city;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *clubID;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *phone;

@end
```

Note: NSString *state; contains the state abbreviation for example: FL

I know how to do this with a single argument but don't know how to check against all strings from `westCoastStates` array. Hope you can help.

Comment: *How do I iterate through allGolfCourses and remove all objects which have a state Abbreviations found in westCoastStates array?*  Maybe you iterate through allGolfCOurses and remove all objects which have a state abbreviation that matches one in westCoastStates.  Start with `while` and continue from there.  (Or actually `for` would be better.)

Comment: It's worth leveraging the enumeration abilities of `NSArray`, both for performance and readability purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about?

```
NSSet* westCoastStatesSet = [NSSet setWithArray:self.westCoastStates];
NSIndexSet* eastCoastGolfCoursesIndexSet = [allGolfCourses indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    GolfCourse* course = (GolfCourse*)obj;
    if ([westCoastStatesSet containsObject:course.state]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}];

NSArray* eastCoastGolfCourses = [allGolfCourses objectsAtIndexes:eastCoastGolfCoursesIndexSet];
```

**Update:** I believe this could be condensed with the use of predicates

```
NSPredicate *inPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"!(state IN %@)", self.westCoastStates];
NSArray* eastCoastGolfCourses = [allGolfCourses filteredArrayUsingPredicate:inPredicate];
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < allGolfCourses.length;) {
    Course* course = [allGolfCourses objectAtIndex:i];
    if (<is course in one of the "bad" states?>) {
       [allGolfCourse removeObjectAtIndex:i];
    }
    else {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can quickly iterate on an array like this:

```
[self.allGolfCourses enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    GolfCourse *currentGolfCourse = (GolfCourse *)obj;
    if(![self.westCoastStates containsObject:currentGolfCourse.state]){
        [self.eastCoastStates addObject:currentGolfCourse];
    }
}];
```