# I have 2 arrays. Need to delete string from one of the arrays, if it is found in both of them

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have 2 NSMutableArray objects. One is called "friendsNotInDatabase" and the other is called "friendsInDatabase."

They both contain NSStrings that are names like John, Steve, Mary.

I need to make it so that if one of the names in the "friendsNotInDatabase" array is found in the "friendsInDatabase" array, that it will be removed from "friendsNotInDatabase."

I have been trying to think of a logical way to do this for several hours now and I am completely stuck.

Thanks for the help.

EDIT -  So far here is the code that I have:

```
int i;

for(i = 0; i < self.friendsInDatabase.count; i++) {

NSString *string;

string = [self.friendsInDatabase objectAtIndex:i];

}
```

I need a way to take the value of "string" and check to see if it is stored in the other array called "friendsNotInDatabase".

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on? Do you know how to check if an array contains a particular object? Do you know how to remove an object from a mutable array? (Hint: there are built-in methods to do both of these things.)

Comment: Samo, samo, samo...  Run a search, run a search, run a search.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove particular objects from an array based on objects from another array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219988/remove-particular-objects-from-an-array-based-on-objects-from-another-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Xu Yin. Your question is a little vague on what exactly you want.

```
NSString *searchString = @"Jane";

if([friendsInDatabase containsObject:searchString])
    [friendsNotInDatabase removeObject:searchString];
```

Comment: This worked perfectly once I setup the for loop and had the string. Thank you!

Comment: You are very welcome. Glad to be of help. I beat @matt to an answer. Gotta make a note on my calendar :)

Comment: Upvoted for beating @matt!

Answer (score 1):

you can change `NSMutableOrderedSet` to `NSMutableSet` if order is not important

```
NSMutableArray *friendsNotInDatabase = //...
NSMutableArray *friendsInDatabase = //...

NSSet *indb = [NSSet setWithArray:friendsInDatabase];
NSMutableOrderedSet *notindb = [NSMutableOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:friendsNotInDatabase];
[notindb minusSet:indb];
friendsNotInDatabase = [[notindb array] mutableCopy];
```

BTW, from my understanding, they should be `NSSet` for start, not `NSArray`

Comment: I agree; sets are not used enough by most people. And besides having `minusSet:` built right in, for answering questions of containment they are way faster than arrays.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to do this is to solve it in reverse. Make a third (empty) mutable array. Walk through the `friendsNotInDatabase` array and add each name to the third array but only if *not* in the `friendsInDatabase` array! Now replace `friendsNotInDatabase` by the third array.

```
NSMutableArray* third = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSString* aName in friendsNotInDatabase)
    if (NSNotFound == [friendsInDatabase indexOfObject: aName]
        [third addObject: aName];
friendsNotInDatase = third;
```

Comment: use `containsObject:` instead of `indexOfObject:`?

Comment: @BryanChen Whatever. :) Point is just to show that "do not add" is the same as "remove".